# Search functionality in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I'm learning to create a webapp using asp.net and C#. And I already create a basic user database webapp. Wherein I display all the user information in a tabled manner. So basically I just used the table element from HTML and not the gridview control.

But I have a problem right now, I want to add a user search functionality wherein I will just input the user's firstname in the search box, so then when I click the search button it will  display the user information in a table format. So I don't know how to implement it because I used the table element not the gridview. Where to I write the data that I searched?

Please advise.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what you use to display the results, you can reuse that code. The only thing you need to change is the way you select the data from the database based on the firstname.

Comment: I see thanks, I'm using response.write method to write the results. Do I need to refresh the page to get the new result?

Comment: Yes you need to reload since you are creating the html server-side.
In your Page Load function check if Request.Form contains the firstname value, if it exists you need to change the query to the db otherwise select all rows.